# Experiencing a lag while dismissing the soft keyboard on pressing the back button[Xamarin Forms Marshmallow]

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In our Xamarin Forms App, There is a screen with 5 custom entries(EditText in android)as shown in the attached image.

The issue is, after we edit the last text field and when the back button is pressed, there is a delay for the keyboard to disappear and also the last two fields repeats below the button.

We are using `SoftInput.AdjustPan` as `WindowSoftInputMode` to adjust the screen when the keypad opens up.

Comment: I can not reprodece your issue, just give you some suggtion. Please check the on back button press event, if it is editing the follow two entries. Follow the name of the last tow entries if it is edited at any strange place.

Comment: It seems to be a device specific issue and not visible in all the devices. I will update here if the issue still persist. Thank you